# What is the correct way to query this document? (If the index is correct)

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, bigchaindb

I've a BigChainDB docker container running in my machine and I'm trying to store and retrieve geospatial data.
I've created through the MongoDB interface a 2dsphere index "location" in the "metadata" collection.
I've checked with the command:

```
db.people.getIndexes()
```

And I think that everything it's ok, in fact the result is this:

```
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "loc" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "loc_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "bigchain.metadata",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }
```

The document that I've inserted to try some spatial queries is (this is the result of a db.metadata.findOne() query):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccab10a2ce1b70022823a0f"),
    "id" : "752ee9abccf83c7fd25d86c9a7d12229ae292fa27544f6881f1dbf97ccd8b413",
    "metadata" : {
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                22.170872,
                113.578749
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use this spatial query nothing is retrieved:

```
db.metadata.find(
{ 
"metadata": {
     "location": {
       $near: {
         $geometry: {
            type: "Point" ,
            coordinates: [ 22 , 113 ]
         },
       }
     }
  }
})
```

I'm doing anything wrong, or is there the possibility that the index doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

The first is that the index is on the field `loc` whereas your query is querying `metadata.location`.

If you try creating a 2dsphere index on `metadata.location` you will see the 2nd error:

```
"errmsg" : "invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 22.0, 113.0 ] }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 22 lat: 113",
```

This error shows that the GEOJSON point defined in your document is invalid, as the latitude value of 113 is [outside the acceptable range of [-90, 90]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geojson-objects).

You would need to correct the data to be valid GEOJSON before indexing.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the index, that is "location" now, and I used as long and lat value [ 44, 11 ], but with the same query I've no results.

Comment: I've found the error, I need to use as index location that is nested into "metadata" field, like this:  db.metadata.createIndex( { metadata.location: "2dsphere" } ), the problem is that doing this I encounter this error:  SyntaxError: missing : after property id